# Is $f : A \times B \to B \times A$ defined by $f(x,y)=(y,x)$ surjective and/or injective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

> Determine whether the following function is injective and/or surjective.
>
> $f : A \times B \to B \times A$ defined by $f(x,y)=(y,x)$

For injective:

Assume that $f(a,b) = f(c,d)$. For $f$ to be injective, $a=c$ and $b=d$.

$f(a,b) = f(c,d)$

$(b,a) = (d,c)$

$b=d$ and $c=a$.

Hence, it is injective.

For surjective:

To prove that $f$ is surjective, we must prove that for every $(c,d) \in B \times A$, there exists $(a,b)$ in $A \times B$ such that $f(a,b) = (c,d)$

$f(a,b) = (c,d)$

$(b,a) = (c,d)$

$b=c$ and $a=d$

$f(d,c) = (c,d)$.

Hence it is surjective.

I am not entirely sure if this is correct so would love some feedback on this.

Comment: It's correct. Not every exercise has depth.

Comment: Maybe do you mean $f((x,y))=(y,x)$?

Answer (score 1):

As @quasi states in the comments, your reasoning is correct; however, your notation is somewhat abusive as @MichaelRozenberg points out: try, instead of, say, $f(a,b)$, to write $f((a,b))$.

Comment: It's abusive but... it's an abuse *all* mathematicians make.  This could be the notation the OP's texts *instructs* one to use.

Comment: That's a fair comment, @fleablood. I can only speak for myself but I think there is some pedagogical strength to insisting, at least at this level, that the argument of $f$ be $(a,b)$, *etc.*; I do indeed make such abuses in my research when the context is clear though.

Comment: I wouldn't disagree either.  I was going to comment that rather than claiming we need to show $a=c; b=d$ that technically what we are required to do is show $(a,b) = (c,d)$... which is the exact same thing, and I was wondering how I'd put it in words why that was important... and then I realized this thread is nearly two years old so it might be best to leave it.